# Есть сервис Сервис (Служба) написанная на C# и есть приложение WPF с интерфейсом. Нужно как-то их "связать"

Tags: c#, wpf, service, служба

Есть некая задача, заключается она в том, чтобы из приложения WPF получать данные — выбранный интервал между резервной копией (1 час, 6 часов и т.д.) и пути папок — Начальной (Папка файлы из которой нужно скопировать) и конечная (куда будут копироваться файлы из начальной), эти данные должна получать служба и, после нажатия определенной кнопки в WPF, служба запускалась с заданными параметрами. Доступ к исходным кодам как сервиса, так и приложения WPF есть, осталось только "связать" их. Была идея сделать файл "save.txt" где будут храниться данные, из сервиса их читать, а для запуска сервиса, при нажатии кнопки запускать bat'ник, в котором будет прописан старт сервиса. Но мне кажется это костыль и это можно реализовать проще и лучше. Всё пишется на C# с .NET Framework 4

Подразумевается, что программа будет стоять на сервере и копировать, к примеру, логи на другой диск (или носитель), а с правами доступа проблем быть не должно, у сис админов есть доступ ко всему.

Comment: Приведите пример Вашего кода для решения поставленной задачи.

Comment: А есть вопрос... у того  пользователя, под которым запускается WPF - "морда" - есть права на старт - стоп службы? А то иногда пользователь работает именнно под "пользователем", и такого рпава у него нет

Comment: `.NET Framework 4` это что-то очень старое, я не умею на этом писать. А так, есть Named Pipes для обмена данными между запущенными приложениями, правда не знаю, поддерживаются ли они в такой старой версии фреймворка.

Comment: Сервис принимает параметры - вот через них и передавайте. [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer#define-what-occurs-when-the-service-starts), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.start?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Comment: Что по сервисом-службой понимается? Это служба Windows или что?

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял вашу задачу...
То не нужно никаких батников, есть несколько вариантов:

1. Сделать обычное приложение и закинуть его в автозапуск, которое прячет свое окно и висит в трее, и просто разворачиваете его и меняете настройки когда надо, а приложение свой планировщик держит в файле конфигурации, но это вариант если пользователь у компа один.
2. В случае когда пользователей много - подобное приложение, без окна, а сам интерфейс в виде отдельного приложения подключается с приложению-службе и командами запускает функции и меняет конфигурацию.
3. Не держать никакую службу-сервер, использовать встроенный "планировщик заданий" винды, там и таймеры готовые есть, и триггеры. Планировщик будет запускать пресловутый батник, а вы своей программой тупо менять содержимое батника и редактировать параметры задания планировщика.
4. Сделать полноценную службу, и либо через внутренние команды (о которых я вам к сожалению не скажу) либо через сеть управлять службой.

Если выбираете одиночное приложение - всё очень просто, если сетевое - то можно отправлять/принимать команды/конфигурацию различными способами, могут подойти Socket или HTTPListener, тут подробнее что и как: https://metanit.com/sharp/net/3.2.php

Заведите класс конфигурации, например:

```
class ConfigBackup
{ 
    public string SourceFolder { get; set; }
    public string DestinationFolder { get; set; }
    public int BackupIntervalHours { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastCopyEntry { get; set; }
}
```

И сохраняйте/загружайте через формат Json.
Для этого подключите Nuget пакет: Newtonsoft.Json
Сохранение и загрузка соответственно:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
ConfigBackup cbackup = new ConfigBackup();
//сохранить:
string cfg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cbackup, Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText("config.cfg", cfg);
//загрузить:
string cfg = File.ReadAllText("config.cfg");
cbackup = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConfigBackup>(cfg);
```